# .Net Owin Authentication Failures... in a bizarre way

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

I have some "out of the box" .net authentication code:

```
Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout := False)

    Select Case result
        Case SignInStatus.Success
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                Exit Select
```

I have local, Facebook and Google authentication all working.

Now, the VERY strange part.

User 1 logs in, no problem

User 2 logs in... returns "SignInStatus.Success", but "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity" is nothing.

BUT WAIT! There's more!

If I open and save web.config (making no changes) User 2 can now log in!
Now I have 2 users logged in, a third does the same: Can't log in until I save web.config (which would restart the app pool)

So, the question is: WTF is going on here?

Comment: Still banging my head here. Same thing happens on my development machine as does on the server. You must restart the app pool after each user signs in or the next user fails (with no error and apparent success)

Comment: Also of note, when signing in as "User 2", if I enter a bad password, it fails properly. It also exibits the same behavior if I register a new user... the new user doesn't get signed in unless I first restart the application pool

Comment: there are 2 things here: (1) it appears that you are just using the Identity framework for authentication, you probably don't need OWin, unless you are referencing OAuth to Facebook and Google; without your other code, I can't tell where you need Owin involved; (2) How did you register ApplicationUserManager, by any chance you get it registered as singleton?

Comment: It was all the stock code that came with creating a new project, and yes, I have both Google and Facebook authentication in there. After all was said and done, I created a new, empty project, added the routes and values to get Facebook and Google working and everything worked fine. Moved all the code I had written into the new project and all was good. Still no idea what was going on, but at least I can move forward.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio authorization template sets the LoginPath property of the CookieAuthenticationOptions class in Startup.Auth.cs. This handles the ReturnUrl logic and duplicates the functionality in the IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl method. If this is your problem you'll see 302 responses in your IIS logs when you post to your login page. I fixed this by commenting out the call to IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl in the Login page.

You can read more about the LoginPath property and what it does [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.loginpath(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath).